# Problem with checking NaN as truthy/falsy

Tags: javascript, arrays, nan

I'm doing an algorithm challenge on freecodecamp, and the solution they provided is really neat and tidy:

```
function bouncer(arr) {
  return arr.filter(Boolean);
}
```

Unfortunately, being a noob and not thinking of that higher-order function, I created this verbose monster instead:

```
 function bouncer(arr) {
    let truthyArray = [];
    let falsyArray = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i] == false || arr[i] === null || arr[i] === NaN || arr[i] === undefined) {
            falsyArray.push(arr[i]);
        } else {
            truthyArray.push(arr[i]);
        }
    }
    return truthyArray;
}
```

It seemed to get the job done in previous tests. However, NaN is not playing along.

```
bouncer([1, null, NaN, 2, undefined])
```

returns:

```
[1, NaN, 2]
```

Any thoughts on how to test NaN as well?

Comment: `bouncer([false, null, 0, NaN, undefined, ""]) 
returns:

[1, NaN, 2]` Huh? Where did the `1` and `2`s come from? I can't reproduce

Comment: This line `if (arr[i] == false || arr[i] === null || arr[i] === NaN || arr[i] === undefined)` can also be done like `if ( ! arr[i] )`.. You're almost checking all falsy values there.

Comment: Sorry, edited and corrected the function call and thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that `NaN !== NaN`:

```js
console.log(NaN === NaN);
```

(which makes sense, because `NaN` is just a placeholder for where one would *expect* a number, but a numeric value couldn't be calculated - for example, `0 / 0` (`NaN`) `!== ('foo' * 3)` (`NaN`))

Instead, you can use `Number.isNaN`, which will check whether the passed value is a `Number` and is `NaN`.

```js
console.log(Number.isNaN(NaN));

function bouncer(arr) {
  let truthyArray = [];
  let falsyArray = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i] == false || arr[i] === null || Number.isNaN(arr[i]) || arr[i] === undefined) {
      falsyArray.push(arr[i]);
    } else {
      truthyArray.push(arr[i]);
    }
  }
  return truthyArray;
}

console.log(bouncer([false, null, 0, NaN, undefined, ""]));
```

Make sure to use `Number.isNaN` and not plain `isNaN`, which will undesirably exclude truthy non-numbers.

Comment: Hello again! Thank you, Akrion commented as well but I felt I left out the important detail that things that are truthy (and not numbers) need to pass as well. Your solution resolved that as well! Kudos!